# How to declare the welcome file (e.g. index.html) in app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, configuration, yaml

In Java, the web.xml might contain some `<welcome-file>` elements. I am trying to do something equivalent in python with no luck.

```
application: wk
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_dir: docs

welcome_files:
- index.html
```

Any thoughts? I get an error that "welcome_files" is not understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility:

```
application: wk
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /.*
  static_files: static
  upload: static
```

Comment: This is correct. 'welcome_file' only exists in Java because the Java config doesn't support this.

Comment: Robert, please see @Karens' answer below and revise yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer does not work any more. You have to do the following:

```
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/\1
```

Comment: Can't use regexp `\1` in `upload`. Change last line to `upload: static/.*`

Answer (score 0):

Route the empty string to index.html.

```
- url: /$
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```